# google api geocoding returns json object different than official docs

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I've been successfully using the google api for geocoding, but when I originally set it up I noticed that the object returned is not quite the same as described in the google documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses

I used console.dir to inspect the object in chrome.

Unless I've misunderstood (quite likely), I can retrieve the latitude and longitude for the supplied address as follows:

```
lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

Except, that wasn't working, and when I investigated I found that lat and lng were at `results[0].geometry.location.d` and `results[0].geometry.location.e` respectively.

All good until today it stopped working. Investigating I found that lat & lng are being returned via `results[0].geometry.location.k` & `results[0].location.A`.

Presumably this will break again before too long.

If I inspect results[0].geometry.location.lat it contains this:

```
function (){
\"use strict\";
return this[a]}
```

Anyone recognise that?

Comment: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json...` returns lat/lng format which is according to docs. `geocoder.geocode()` returns `results[0].geometry.location` with properties `A` and `k` which could most probably change in the future. Do you talk about `geocode()` function output?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm using geocoder.geocode(), although I set it up as per the docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The results returned from the geocode-method of the Javascript-Geocoder is already translated to be used with the Javascript-API(the linked documentation is for the Geocoding-Webservice, not for the Maps-Javascript-API).

`geometry.location` is not a plain object, it's a `google.maps.LatLng`

you must use the methods `lat()` and `lng()` of `geometry.location` to retrieve latitude and longitude.

[**Specification  of GeocoderGeometry**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry)

In your case that would mean using it like this:

`lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I had somehow missed that. I edited your answer slightly for the benefit of anyone new looking at this question.

Comment: Ok, but during development, the lat() and lng() methods did not exist in the object I was getting back! That's the way I originally had the code, and it was broken, just like the OP.